# .Net Core httpClient authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I have a WebClient interface to an API, which works,

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an empty instance of the NetworkCredential class.
            NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("", "", "");
            myCredentials.Domain = "";
            myCredentials.UserName = "myusername";
            myCredentials.Password = "mypassword";
            var url = "http://blablabla";
            // Create a WebRequest with the specified URL.
            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            myWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentials;

            // Send the request and wait for a response.
            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            // Process the response.
            Stream dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content. 
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content. 
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            Console.ReadKey();
            // Release the resources of the response object.
            myWebResponse.Close();
        }
    }
```

But cannot get the equivalent going with Core v2, this is my current code, but I've been through a number of variations and Google searches; would welcome some help. The API is a JSON feed.

```
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        ProcessWebRequest().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task ProcessWebRequest()
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        var url = "http://blablabla";

        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "myusername", "mypassword"))));

        var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var msg = await stringTask;
        Console.Write(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: These are both just console examples

Comment: So what is the problem with .Net Core code? You get 401 error?

Comment: Sorry, yes, unauthorized 401

Comment: You can use Fiddler to capture both requests and compare the difference.

Comment: Good idea Faizan, but thought I'd be doing something studpid. .Net version 4.7 by the way.

Comment: In the first example you're using Windows credentials. In the second you're using both Windows credentials and Basic authentication. I doubt that was your intent, not sure if you just copied that from somewhere or what but try removing the entire line that starts with `client.DefaultRequestHeaders...`

Comment: Thanks Todd. Just trying different variations, monkey fashion. Same effect.Looking at Fiddler output, they are almost identical. www Authenticate hash is different in a few chars; assume the time changes
On the succesful attempt I get two 401 results then a 200 with the data; unsuccesful gives three 401 results. I cannot see much difference in the raw results.

Comment: Looking at the headers, the unsuccessful attempt has a Transport > Connection:Keep-Alive in the second of the 401 results, whereas the successful attempt doesn't.

Comment: Seems like a very basic thing to do, is it possible to do it with netcore? I'm surprised no answer came out...